# What to do when you have multiple good answers?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Alright, this is probably a weird question but sometimes I get two competing answers to a question both of which I think are very good. So, in case of a tie, how do I choose the answers?

Comment: If they truly are completely equal in quality, you'll have to flip a coin or something. In general, I try to give it to the most fitting for the question. The style and content of a question will draw a given type of reader. The green check should go to the answer likely to be most helpful to that type of reader. I didn't make this an answer because I think rob's answer is good and officially correct. This is merely an opinioned suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you feel like two (or more!) answers deserve recognition, but you have only one green checkmark, you could reward the others with a [bounty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: Then again, a bounty is worth *more* than a green checkmark, so you got to choose again.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Technically, you could offer a bounty to both such that the total is the same (it would take a while though). Although, I completely agree with you that, in the end, you still have to make a choice because the one with the green check is likely to receive more upvotes afterward due to being first viewed